# Diferencia entre distintos Framework para generar o crear aplicaciones nativas u otras

Tags: android-studio, firebase, react-native, kotlin, aplicación-movil

Hoy en día existen distintos `Frameworks` para la creación de aplicaciones ya sea solo para `Android` o en conjunto con `iOS` tales como:

- Android Studio
- Kotlin
- React Native
- Ionic
- Flutter
- Xamarin
- Firebase
- Entre otras.

He observado preguntas similares en **StackOverflow** inglés, realmente no estaría mal que se de la oportunidad de mantener activo este hilo de hacer un breve introductorio de las framework más utilizadas para la creación de aplicaciones, las características ventajas y, desventajas.

Aplicaciones Nativas, generadoras de interfaz y, multi plataformas.

En la web existen varios artículos muy interesantes pero no hay mejor respuesta, que el conocimiento de vosostros, experiencia, trabajos/proyectos realizados y, más.

No es necesario responder cada una de ellas puede ser una, denle la oportunidad de que esté abierta.

Comment: Hola @Fátima estos tipos de preguntas normalmente no son bienvenidas dadas a qué son muy amplias o a base de opiniones sin embargo participaré y, se queda abierta la pregunta agregaré una recompensa solo porque me llama la atención.

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, pero demasiado amplia. La única forma en que quizá podría existir sería como Wiki de comunidad donde varios usuarios aporten sus experiencias o en varias respuestas según el nivel de experiencia de quienes respondan. Sea como sea me temo que se aleja bastante del formato de este sitio. En el motivo de cierre **Necesita ser más específica** dice precisamente: *Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez.*, etc. aparte de eso, las respuestas serían basadas en **Opiniones**. Dos motivos fuertes de cierre.

Comment: @A.Cedano La edité porque la pregunta en si, es interesante a lo mejor pueda ser considerada aunque es casi imposible que sea así. Pero bueno estaré pendiente por aquí.

Comment: @IniDesing.com nos encontramos en el sitio en español, revisa lo que sugiere el centro de ayuda acerca de las preguntas [ask], por cierto ahora que veo este tipo de preguntas que estàn teniendo votos te sugiero revisar tambièn : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1725/c%c3%b3mo-deben-gestionarse-las-cuentas-t%c3%adtere-en-stack-exchange